# Completely load a link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to promote an advertiser and when the user clicks on the advertiser link, it redirects 5-6 times through different links (for tracking purposes) before reaching the advertiser's website.

Is it possible to show some kind of loading icon on the page on which the user clicks on the link and then redirect the user to the advertiser's website when the link is completely loaded?

I searched and found this code, but I am not sure how to implement this in my case:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>

//paste this code under the head tag or in a separate js file.
 // Wait for window load
 $(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
 });
```

```css
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background: url(images/loader-64x/Preloader_2.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

Comment: Show us your code what you have done so far and what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Everything is possible. But the question is what have you done already to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it redirects to someone elses website, you cannot change the content of those websites to have a loading icon.

You could load it in an iframe and when the iframe has not changed its location in, say, 5 seconds, show the iframe as the whole page and hide the loading icon. You can also set the target to '_top' so it changes the url in the browser whenever you click on a link.

```
<a href="http://example.com/tracking-link" class="tracking">Click!</a>
<iframe id="preload-frame" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;" hidden>
<script type="text/javascript">var iframe=false;</script>
</iframe>
<div class="se-pre-con" hidden></div>
```

```
var frame = document.getElementById('preload-frame');
onclickConstructor = function (href) {
  return function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('se-pre-con')[0].removeAttribute('hidden');
    var timer;
    var cleanup = function() {
      frame.removeAttribute('hidden');
      frame.setAttribute('target', '_top');
      document.getElementsByClassName('se-pre-con')[0].setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    }
    frame.onload = function() {  // Whenever the iframe (re)loads the whole page
      if (timer) {
        (clearTimeout || clearInterval)(timer);
      }
      timer = setTimeout(cleanup);
    }
    frame.src = href;
  };
}

if (iframe !== false) {
  var trackingLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tracking'), function(el); 
  for (var i = 0; i < trackingLinks.length; i++) {
    el.onclick = onclickConstructor(el.href);
    el.href = 'javascript:void(0);';
  };
}
```